# Not send http request in service android

Tags: android, service

I'm trying to send a request to the local server in the background. **But I fail.**

```
    class MyService2 : Service() {
     ..........
    fun Check_Presence(){
    var url="http://192.168.1.158/cgi-bin/cp/login.sh"

    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    val postRequest = object : StringRequest(
        Request.Method.POST, url,
        Response.Listener {response ->
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  "response"+response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        },
        Response.ErrorListener() { response ->
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  "Not Send Request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    ) {
        override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
            val params = HashMap<String, String>()
            params["status"] = "1"
            return params
        }
    }
    queue.add(postRequest)

     }
    }
```

---

manifest file :

```
<application
........
  <service
    android:name=".MyService2"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
    </service>
</application>
```

---

MainActivity :

```
val serviceClass = MyService2::class.java
val serviceIntent = Intent(this, serviceClass)
this.startService(serviceIntent)
```

As long as the program is running, it works correctly and displays the response ... message.
But when I close the program, the program displays the "Not Send Request" message.
Note:The Check_Presence function runs every minute.

---

**When I checked the Internet at the service, I realized that the internet was not connected.**

```
fun Check_Internet(){
    val connectivityManager=this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    val networkInfo=connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
    if (networkInfo!=null && networkInfo.isConnected) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "INTENET OK : ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "NO INTERNET : ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

*Please help me.*
*My device : Android 8*

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind I would ask you to check or perform 3 things-

1. Have you taken Internet and Network Access permission in your manifest?
2. Please use Retrofit library for HTTP purposes as Retrofit is a highly maintained, easy and efficient library
3. Before you call your localhost server (or whatsoever) test it with Postman app to get a clear view of your network status, server performance etc.